# Trigonometric expression maxima and minima question.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

The question is as follows:

The minimum value of

$$f(x)=\frac{(\sec \theta + \tan \theta)(1 - \sin \theta)\sec \theta}{(1+\tan \theta + \sec \theta)(1+\cot \theta - \operatorname{cosec} \theta)}$$

lies between

(A) $0.2$ and $0.4$

(B) $0.4$ and $0.6$

(C) $0.6$ and $0.8$

(D) $0.8$ and $1$

I have tried using numerous trigonometric identities but to no avail.

Any sort of help with simplifying the trigonometric expression would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: How did you try using trig identities? Where would you even start with that? Looking at a big mess like this, you could try looking for common factors in the bracketed terms to factor out, or you could try multiplying the brackets together to see what the result is. But staring at the formula alongside a table of trig identities will go nowhere, of course.

Comment: @David K i figured something like the identity $$1 + \cot^2 \theta = \csc^2 \theta$$ would work in simplfying the equation

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but you'll need to buckle down and do some operations on the expression in order to get any terms like those to show up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\frac{(\sec\theta + \tan\theta)(1-\sin\theta)\cos\theta}{(1+\tan\theta+\sec\theta)(1-\cot\theta-\operatorname{cosec}\theta)}$$

Looking at the numerator:

$$\cos\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)=\cos\theta(\frac{1}{\cos\theta}+\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta})=1+\sin\theta, (1+\sin\theta)(1-\sin\theta)=1-\sin^2(\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)$$

Therefore, the numerator is $$\cos^2(\theta)$$

Looking at the denominator:

$$1+\tan\theta+\sec\theta=\frac{1+\sin\theta+\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}, 1-\cot\theta-\operatorname{cosec}\theta=\frac{1-\cos\theta-\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

Multiplying the two terms:

$$\frac{(1+\sin\theta+\cos\theta)(1-(\sin\theta + \cos\theta))}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}=\frac{1-(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}=\frac{-2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}=-2$$

Therefore, the denominator is

$$-2$$

Hence, the overall expression becomes:

$$\fbox{$-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta)$}$$

After that, I think the OP knows what to do to answer the question.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval, I have edited the question.

Comment: Also, AnneBauval, I have not *fully* answered the question. I have just simplified the trigonometric expression (which is what he wanted help with since he stated that he 'threw' "a bunch of trig identities", which indicated that he couldn't simplify the trig expression and wanted help with it). I also stated at the end of my simplification of the trig expression that "I think the OP knows what to do to answer the question".

Comment: Let's see: you made an edit that should never have been approved (you changed the meaning of the question, which was about the entire range of the function, not just the minimum), then you did not just give "any help", you completely reduced the trig function, leaving nothing for OP to do toward that end.

Comment: @DavidK, I admit that the question's meaning was altered (and I will go and change it). As far as the trigonometric expression goes, that is half of the solution to this problem, because then the OP still has to figure out the range of the simplified function. And my last sentence indicates that he knows what to do - all I did was show him **one possible** way of simplifying the expression (there are many ways to do so but all of them lead to $-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta)$).